# how to run a code which is inside a Adapter every second in android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String current_user_id = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    Messages messages = mMessagesList.get(position);
    String from_user = messages.getFrom();

    if (from_user != null && from_user.equals(current_user_id)) {
        holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.messageText.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        holder.messageText.setLayoutParams(params);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
        final long Seen = messages.isSeen();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                if (Seen==1){
                    holder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_background2);
                }else{
                    holder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_background1);
                }


            }
        }, delay);

    }else {
            holder.messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_background2);
            holder.messageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.messageText.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        holder.messageText.setLayoutParams(params);
        }

        holder.messageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
    }
```

Currently im trying to achieve the same like this... but just doesn't seem to happen... i get the desired result only after i refresh the activity... i want the code which is inside the runnable to execute every one second... is my approach correct? please help... thanks in advance

Tried Solution

```
messageList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.message_list);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mAdapter = new AdapterMessages(messagesList);

    messageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    messageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    messageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    final Handler handlerr = new Handler();
    int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
    final int finalDelay1 = delay;
    handlerr.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            handlerr.postDelayed(this, finalDelay1);
        }
    }, delay);
```

Comment: The code written inside adapter's onBindViewHolder will execute every time when you scroll up/down recyclerview.

Comment: i want it to execute every second

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    yourfunction();
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
  }
};

//Start
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Or try Timer

```
//Declare the timer
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
    //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period 
   parameter)
 }

 },
 //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
 0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
1000);
```

Comment: Try with Timer this will help you

Comment: Im new to this approach... where should i put the code

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Activity or Fragment you need to create Handler like below.

Note: Remove Handler related code from the "onBindViewHolder" adapter you just need to Notify your adapter.

(1)Create Handler and Runnable like

```
public static final int TIME=1000;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    //Notify your recyclerview adapter here

    handler.postDelayed(this, TIME);
  }
};
```

(2)Start Handler like

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, TIME);
```

Comment: Still nothing,,, btw where is the adapter even mentioned?

Comment: May i know how and in which file are you calling adapter?

Comment: I'm calling the adapter in an activity named chat... but i cant change the background of a view from the activity,,, it can only be done inside the adapter but its not happening tilll i refresh it...

Comment: I have edited your question code please check adapter code and let me know if still doubt

Comment: How is that supposed to solve the problem? u just made the code shorter

Comment: Now you need to create Handler inside your chat activity same as my answer. and you need to call handler inside your activity

Comment: I dont think i did what u said i guess... i just put your code and added the line setNotifyDatasetChanged... was that all or is there more?... @FalduJaldeep

Comment: I edited my question according to ur answer... was that it or is there more?